# Vim - How do I show a helpful error message when using the arrow keys in insert mode?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vim

I'm trying to stop using the arrow keys in vim. But instead of setting them to `<nop>`, as other people do, I want them to show an error message. This does the thing in normal mode:

```
noremap <up>    :echoerr 'USE K TO GO UP'<CR>
noremap <down>  :echoerr 'USE J TO GO DOWN'<CR>
noremap <left>  :echoerr 'USE H TO GO LEFT'<CR>
noremap <right> :echoerr 'USE L TO GO RIGHT'<CR>
```

I tried to do the same in insert mode, but it didn't work:

```
inoremap <up>    :echoerr 'USE K TO GO UP'<CR>
inoremap <down>  :echoerr 'USE J TO GO DOWN'<CR>
inoremap <left>  :echoerr 'USE H TO GO LEFT'<CR>
inoremap <right> :echoerr 'USE L TO GO RIGHT'<CR>
```

This instead prints `:echoerr 'USE K TO GO UP'` where my cursor is when I press up in insert mode.

How can I fix the `inoremap` directives so this works as I expected? (also, an explanation of why it doesn't work would help).

EDIT: Thanks to all the people that helped me. I ende up using this:

```
noremap <up>    :echom 'USE K TO GO UP'<CR>
noremap <down>  :echom 'USE J TO GO DOWN'<CR>
noremap <left>  :echom 'USE H TO GO LEFT'<CR>
noremap <right> :echom 'USE L TO GO RIGHT'<CR>
inoremap <up>    <ESC>:echom 'USE K TO GO UP'<CR>
inoremap <down>  <ESC>:echom 'USE J TO GO DOWN'<CR>
inoremap <right> <ESC>:echom 'USE L TO GO RIGHT'<CR>
inoremap <left>  <ESC>:echom 'USE H TO GO LEFT'<CR>
```

The vim-autoclose plugin was giving me trouble with the up/down keys on edit mode. I just uninstalled the plugin.

Comment: Just from an aesthetic point of view, using the wrong key isn't a catastrophic failure so you might consider using `echom` for your own sanity.

Comment: @Michael well, what can I say. I hardly see the red error message when I'm in normal mode. I guess I'm used at not looking at the bottom of the screen too much. If anything, I would need to make it *more*  obnoxious (like a message in the center of the screen or anything).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
:inoremap <up> <Esc>:echoerr 'MSG HERE'<CR>
```

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work. I got the following error `E15: Invalid expression: pumvisible() ? '<80>ku' : '^R=<80><fd>R35_FlushBuffer()^M^[:echoerr 'USE K TO GO UP'^M'`. Curiously, it works with left and right. Down also throws the error.

Comment: try running starting vim with `vim -u NONE` if the mappings work it is something conflicting in your vimrc.

Comment: Or a plugin, possibly an autocompletion plugin?

Comment: Running ´vim -u NONE´ If I try that, and pressing up,down,left or right on insert mode, I get the uppercase letters A B C and D, with a newline after each. I confess I'm baffled.

Comment: Ok, it is definitively a plugin thing. I tried running `vim --noplugin` and then I got the error messages on insert mode. I'm accepting your answer, and will hunt down the plugin that interferes with this. Thanks!

Comment: to list your insert mode mappings use `:imap` as @romainl said it look like autocompletion plugin, popup

Comment: I got `@pumvisible() ? '<Up>' : '<C-R>=<SNR>35_FlushBuffer()<CR><Esc>:echoerr 'USE K TO GO UP'<CR>'` A google search seems to indicate this is related with the "completion popup" (I have supertab installed, maybe that's it). Thanks for the help, Eric

Comment: Which version of vim is this? I tried it with gVim, and it didn't work.

Comment: Hi octopusgrabbus, I'm using `Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled May  4 2012 04:09:27)`

Comment: I finally was able to identify the plugin giving me trouble using this command `:verbose imap <up>`. It was vim-autoclose. I removed it and Eric's solution worked just fine.

Answer (score 4):

Rather then using `<Esc>:echoe 'message'<CR>` I would suggest `<C-o>:echoe 'message'<CR>` here: it won’t leave insert mode. `<C-o>:throw 'message'<CR>` to make it more annoying: you’ll get `Press ENTER` prompt, not just highlighted message:

```
inoremap <Up> <C-o>:throw 'USE “<Esc>k” TO GO UP'<CR>
```

. Note that I would also suggest using the equivalent `echohl ErrorMsg | echomsg 'Message' | echohl NONE` instead of `:echoerr`: though it is irrelevant here, but `:echoe` should be forgotten because it is highly context-dependent: unlike `:echom` which never breaks execution and `:throw` which always does this, `:echoe` breaks execution if it is inside the `try` block, and does not do so otherwise. That makes any construct like

```
SomeCommand
if error_cond
    echoe 'abc'
endif
SomeCommand2
```

unstable: you never know whether `SomeCommand2` will or won’t be executed if `error_cond` is true. Irrelevant here because there are no subsequent commands and it is unlikely to be run inside `try` block, but don’t make yourself think that `:echoe` may be a good choice for echoing errors.

Comment: Should't the inoremap be preceded by colons, in any case? :inoremap instead of inoremap.

Comment: @kikito No, if you are going to put it into the vimrc. Colon is required to go to command mode from normal or visual mode, but it is not required otherwise. As it is ignored when not required in some circumstances I use it as a separator: `autocmd VimEnter * :call s:F.detecthgmerge()` and `autocmd VimEnter * call s:F.detecthgmerge()` are complete equivalents, but colon makes it easier to find where the body of an autocommand starts.

Comment: I have decided not to use C-O; the Esc version puts me in normal mode, which is actually something I want anyway. But I'm using :echom now. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You have more pressing issues than trying to use `hjkl` instead of the arrows.

You should read `:help mapping`, for example.

With `inoremap <up> :echoerr 'USE K TO GO UP'<CR>` you instruct Vim to imput `:echoerr 'USE K TO GO UP'<CR>` at the cursor when you press `<Up>`. It is an insert mode mapping, so, as long as you don't include `<Esc>` or `<C-o>` somewhere in the mapped sequence the whole thing will just be inserted as is.

In order to execute the sequence of commands you must first exit insert mode; hence the `<Esc>` in Eric's answer.

Comment: I already have read that page. I mean no offense, but it seems to be written for someone who already knows what to look for. It might be useful to an expert, as a reference, but not for someone trying to learn.

Comment: @kikito If you're just learning I recommend you check out http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/. It's a fairly comprehensive, step-by-step guide to Vim.

Comment: Thanks @Michael, that looks much more appropriate for me.